# Why do we use templates instead of functions?

Tags: c++

Just looking for some good reasons so i could start learning about them :/

Comment: These are two orthognal but related concepts in C++!

Comment: Why use a cookie-cutter instead of a cookie?

Comment: Please refraise your question: did you mean "Why do we use template functions"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To avoid repeating code that would be otherwise identical except for different types.  Sometimes you simply can't rely on implicit conversion or promotion and you can't stuff everything into an object hierarchy.

Comment: ...or to generate code in compile-time. For example, generating parsers from inline C++ with [Boost.Spirit](http://boost-spirit.com/home/).

Answer (score 5):

Templates are an important part of C++, as already mentioned, they allow you to develop functions or Classes that are type generic.  You specify the type when you use them.  You really should learn templates if, for no other reason, to understand boost and the standard template libraries.

These libraries give you a whole suite of containers and algorithms that will work for any built-in or user defined type.

For example, the vector class:

```
  vector<int> v(3);            // Declare a vector of 3 elements.
  v[0] = 7;
  v[1] = v[0] + 3;
  v[2] = v[0] + v[1];          // v[0] == 7, v[1] == 10, v[2] == 17
```

The client of this class specifies this as a vector of int's, but it could have easily been a vector of strings or any other type.

Answer (score 3):

1) Templates are a simple way to save yourself on copy/paste code & then edit it.

```
template<class T>
T Max(const T& a, const T& b){ return (a>b)?a:b: }
```

Will work with int,double,string, and anything else which supports the > symbol.

Yes, you could do it with a macro, but a lot of more complex template examples cannot reasonably be done so.

2) Container classes (vector, list, map) are all templated.

My advice, you MUST learn to use templates. Its useful to know how to write them, as they can be useful to use.
(You can do a lot of really freaky things with templates, but you don't need that stuff).

Answer (score 1):

In order to master templates, it helps to have some exposure to [generic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_programming) and [functional](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) programming. Depending on the task at hand, generic programming can greatly simplify the design of key functionality. Languages like Haskell and F# (among many others) will help you think about problems in ways that fit better with template mechanics.

Once you're comfortable with the semantics of functions as objects, type parameters, "recursive iteration" so to speak, up values, and the like, C++ templates become only a matter of overcoming pitfalls of the language.

You can do some pretty great magic with templates, but it's definitely a good idea to start playing with them in your spare time. Templates can help simplify the conceptual complexity of the problem, but the mechanics of C++ can also make them a bit unwieldy (C++0x will solve some of the big annoyances). It's certainly a good idea to make sure anyone you work with is comfortable with them. You may have to prove yourself worthy to use them in a professional setting. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Do you even know what templates are, to begin with? In the hierarchy of programming language concepts, templates are on a way higher plane than functions. A class(/struct) or function is fine, but bound to certain types. When you write a class vector, it only work for one type (and its subclasses, if a class at all), because you're forced to name the type of the items directly. But using a template, you don't have to care of what type the items are - it is irrelevant to the vector implementation, but you have to use templates to achive this genericy.

That being said, C++ templates suck hard. At least they're there, I appreciate that they are there, and back in the 80s it was all new and modern, but today generic code is possible without all the pain of e.g. template error messages. Nonetheless, they are important and incredibly powerful.

Additionally, C++ templates are turing complete and a sufficently smart programmer with a lot of free time can do mind-blowing things with it. Consider: Boost (one of the greates C++ libraries, many would say) is mostly templates. Not functions. Template functions and classes. Templates.

Comment: That does explain what templates are but not why to use them over functions.

Comment: Once you know what Templates are, you don't ask why to use them over functions. You may still ask why or when or how to use them at all; my point is to illustrate that you don't use templates "instead of functions", but rather use templates to enhance existings functions (or classes).

Comment: "...templates are on a way higher plane than functions." No. This is only true in C++ because of certain design restrictions. A "class" is a specialized syntax over a higher-order function that returns a closure over a dispatcher and additional data. Because of the stack-the-structs-up way that C++ instantiates objects from inherited classes it does not allow passing a constructor the same way as other functions. This restriction is what requires the use of templates; not because "templates are higher than functions". These are all higher-order functions in essence. Turtles all the way down...

Comment: @zxq9 Ya think this is helpful for someone who would ask a question like this?

Comment: Someone who is asking because they are coming from a different paradigm, certainly. Not everyone's introduction to programming was in an OOP language, and the verbiage of OOP is neither consistent with other styles of programming or even remotely consistent among OOP languages. So yes, getting at the bottom of just what a template is may be good, even just as a comment or an aside to someone who comes along later and learned all this stuff under different terms. "Oh! I get it! Its a special syntax over a function that returns a dispatcher's generator!" or whatever it may mean to them.

Answer (score 0):

We overload a function when we need to handle different data types. This approach increases the program's size. The disadvantage is not only that the program length is increased, but also more local variables are created in the memory. A template safely overcomes all the limitations occurring during the overloading function and gives more flexibility to the program.